# Add Thousand Separator in a float value

Tags: delphi-10.1-berlin

I have a problem with a thousand separator.I want to add a thousand separator and a decimal separator in a float value,for example 1000 will be 1.000,00.The decimal separator it works but the thousand separator it doesn't.
So i try to work with FormatSettings.Here is my code for example

```
  workSettings := TFormatSettings.Create;
  workSettings.ThousandSeparator := '.';
  workSettings.DecimalSeparator:= ',';
  if (TryStrToFloat(e_pret.Text,articleInfo.Pret)) then begin
  articleInfo.Pret  := StrToFloat(e_pret.Text,wokSettings);
  end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert string with commas to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/788098/convert-string-with-commas-to-float)

Answer (score 1):

`ThousandsSeparator` and `DecimalSeparator` only make sense in strings, not in binary floats. Look at `FormatFloat()` to create a formatted string with separators in it.

```
workSettings := TFormatSettings.Create;
workSettings.ThousandSeparator := '.';
workSettings.DecimalSeparator := ',';
if TryStrToFloat(e_pret.Text, articleInfo.Pret) then begin
   e_pret.Text := FormatFloat('#,##0.00', articleInfo.Pret, wokSettings);
end;
```